# webform multi column single row SQL Server result to vb variables

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, webforms

Ive looked through a few questions on here today and think I'm going round in circles.

My webform has a number of elements including `username` which is a drop down list (populated by a SQL statement)

On submit of the form i would like the code behind `aspx.vb` file run a `select top 1` query and return a single row of data with 4 columns.

The returned SQL query result 4 columns would only be used later in the aspx.vb file so i want to assign each of the columns to a variable. I'm struggling with this task and assigning the variable the column result from the query.

```
Protected Sub submitbtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submitbtn.Click


    Dim connString1 As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString1)
    Dim sql1 As String = ""

    Dim col1h As String = ""
    Dim col2r As String = ""
    Dim col3title As String = ""
    Dim col4UQN As String = ""

    sql1 = "SELECT TOP 1 col1h,col2r,col3title, col4UNQ  from tblDistinctUserOHR where colID_Username= '" + username + "' "

    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(sql1, conn)
'open the connection
'run the sql
'the result will always be found but in case its not some form of safety catch (the variables stay as empty strings 
'assign the results to the variables
'close connections
'lots of other code 
    End Sub
```

could someone point me in the right direction to run the SQL and assign the result to the the variables. I've been reading about `ExecuteScalar()` and `SqlDataReader` but that doesn't seem to be the correct option as the only examples I've found handle a single result or lots of rows with a single column

Thanks for any samples and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    If dt.Rows.Count < 0 Then
        col1h = dt.Rows(0).Item("col1h")
        col2r = dt.Rows(0).Item("col2r")
        col3title = dt.Rows(0).Item("col3title")
        col4UQN = dt.Rows(0).Item("col4UQN")
    Else
        'No rows found
    End If
```